# Adding elements to ArrayList while using Iterator in Java

Tags: java, iterator, arraylist

I had a problem with adding elements to my `ArrayList` while using an `Iterator`. In the following code it gives me this output:

```
a
k
s
```

But still it misses the one I had added through iterator. i.e I am missing `r` in my output. Is there a way I can add elements to an `ArrayList` using an `Iterator`?

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.ListIterator;
public class Test 
{
public static void main(String args[])
{
    ArrayList<String> array_test= new ArrayList<String>();
    array_test.add("a");
    array_test.add("k");
    array_test.add("d");
    array_test.add("s");
    array_test.remove("d");
    ListIterator<String> it=array_test.listIterator();
    while(it.hasNext())
    {   
        String link=it.next();  
        it.add("r");
        System.out.println(link);

    }   
    //System.out.println("Contents of arrays list "+array_test);
}


}
```

Comment: What do you expect your output to be ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sorry for my late reply. Here is how i resolved this issue.

```
for(ListIterator it=array_test.listIterator();it.hasNext();){ 
 String link=it.next(); 
   it.add("r");
   it.previous();
   it.add("kk");
   it.previous();
System.out.println(link);  
}
```

Comment: Glad you got it sorted out after those three years! But this doesn't look like it'll terminate. Each time around the loop, you take one item off and add two?

Answer (score 2):

Check the [Javadoc](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/ListIterator.html#add%28E%29). It is working as documented. Adding an element during an iteration doesn't return that element via the iterator unless you go backwards.

Comment: Thanks for you replay. i am unable to add new elements when i tried using iterator. as i specified, i was trying to add r in while loop. which is not working.

Comment: -1: You should at least quote the relevant part from the documentation.

Comment: It is working.  The second print statement, which you have commented out, should include all four letters.

Comment: @BjörnPollex I disagree completely. The documentation is there to be read. The specification or the wording may change slightly, which would make the quotation obsolete. The point here is that the OP hasn't understood or more probably even read the Javadoc at all.

Comment: @jbrookover your comment is irrelevant to my answer. If you have an answer of your own I suggest you post it.

Comment: @EJP My problem was with usage of the element added in same loop.

Comment: @user1033335 exactly so, and that's why you should read the Javadoc I cited.

Comment: the elements are getting added but it doesnt show up in the same loop. It is shown up in the second print statement i had used. i want r to be used in while instead. is there any way for that.

Comment: @EJP thanks alot. i got what you were saying. it was appended to previous index. sorry for asking the same again. i was newbie, it was helpful.

Comment: @EJP - Sorry, neglected to direct my comment to OP.  His comment on your post stated "trying to add r in while loop. which is not working".  I was explaining that it was working and tried to clarify the behavior that I can see discussed in later comments.